# PYTHON2 Failed building wheel PyAudio & PortAudio

Tags: python, module, pyaudio

I have problem on PyAudio and PortAudio, i want to use speech_recognition so speech_recognition needs PyAudio module and i tried to install but its not working i search almost everything
And im using ParrotOS & Python 2.7.16.

So i tried that;

```
pip install install clang
```

`apt-get install & apt-get update` but thats doesnt work

When i write the console this code;

```
sudo pip install portaudio
```

or

```
sudo pip install PyAudio
```

its shows me this;

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-934KKj/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-tVvPhL --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-UboFgi/python2.7-2.7.16~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
  src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
   #include "portaudio.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
```

and more fail messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev
pip install pyaudio
```

and later i install pyaudio :)